# trying to upload video to instagram form nodejs

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

i am trying to upload video to instagram from a npm module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api

using the function but it gives me promise rejection error

```
Upload.video(session,'./path/to/your/video.mp4','./path/to/your/coverImg.jpg')
.then(function(upload) {
    return Media.configureVideo(session, upload.uploadId, 'akward caption', uploadInfo.durationms);
})
.then(function(medium) {
    // we configure medium, it is now visible with caption 
    console.log(medium.params)
})
```

Comment: How people can help you when you don't give the rejection error?

Comment: no Instagram doesn't provide any API to upload videos